# Php $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] alway return get

Tags: php, http

I'm writing some code in my localhost.

**index.php:**

```
   $task = null;

    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

    var_dump($method);

    //initialize data
    HttpProtocol::init();

    if (empty($method))
        exitApp("unknown method");

    if ($method == HttpProtocol::get())
        $task = new WebhookVerifyTask();
    else if ($method == HttpProtocol::post())
        $task = new ProcessFacebookEventTask();
    if (is_null($task))
        exitApp("unknown method");

    $task->start();
    http_response_code(200);
```

it doesn't matter if I send a GET or POST request, the $method will always be GET.
When trying PUT or DELETE - it changes perfectly..

What could cause the $method to always be GET even when POST ?

**UPDATE**
apparently when i'm sending the request to localhost/path - the above behaviour occur. if i'm sending it to localhost/path/ - the post works perfectly.

Comment: How you are calling your current_filename.php ? please include in your question

Comment: index.php. updated

Comment: Your update also answers your question. if it's /path, but there's no such file, the web server automatically redirects you to /path/ instead.

Comment: when it does this redirection - he does not do it completely with all the request data and methods ?

Answer (score 0):

> apparently when i'm sending the request to localhost/path - the above behaviour occur. if i'm sending it to localhost/path/ - the post works perfectly

> Your update also answers your question. if it's /path, but there's no such file, the web server automatically redirects you to /path/ instead. – [Janno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38629927/php-serverrequest-method-alway-return-get#comment64644218_38629927)

> when it does this redirection - he does not do it completely with all the request data and methods ?

It cannot. The web server decides to tell the client that it should try another request to a different URL. The web server responds with a `302 Found` status code and a `Location: http://localhost/path/` header. This causes the client to make another HTTP request to that new location, **and that new request will always be a `GET` request.** `POST` requests cannot be redirected. (Well, theoretically they can be with a `307 Temporary Redirect`, but in practice that is not widely supported.)

You need to make your request to the canonical URL directly so as to not cause a redirect.